# Is there a way to stop wasting subjective but good questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm well aware that the point of this site is supposed to be answering questions, and not "debate" or opinion.  While I agree that debate is best in a chat or forum context (I also wish we had a true forum hosted here), collecting the subjective opinions of our experienced technical peers or even things like technology recommendations is not worthless. The information subjective questions gather can be *very* valuable and insightful. If they weren't valuable they wouldn't be getting asked constantly while often getting dozens of upvotes (before getting closed!).

Is there any way to make subjective topics "okay" here? I'm not talking about encouraging debate in the comments section (although if it happens, who cares?), but I am thinking of something similar to the Community Wiki tag.  It doesn't need to impact user point counts at all (but it should still allow vote tallying so we can see how popular our viewpoints are and encourage self-reflection).

The main problem with "go away and ask that somewhere else!" is that we all know there really isn't an equally popular alternative for many topics.  The community here dwarfs all others, why not find a way to stop suppressing simple information gathering research?  If it has to be a whole new site or a special checkbox-option, so be it.

Aren't we squandering a potentially massive resource by blindly adhering to this single strict format?

**Edit: I shouldn't have connected this to a feature request or changing anything in SO at all--that wasn't the intent. The intent here was for a discussion on how to fill the desire many users have for such conversations, not to propose a solution. I agree that SO's main content shouldn't be crowded out with this type of content. The "vote" here has no meaning as this wasn't a proposal. I'll remove the feature-request tag as that option seems to have distracted from the discussion.**

Comment: Related on Meta.Programmers.SE: [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980) and [Where can I have subjective discussions about programming?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6763/40980)

Comment: Interesting-- I didn't realize we were so closed-minded here that we have to downvote a non-confrontational and well intentioned question posted on a site meant to ask questions. Oh well.

Comment: Are you really complaining about your feature-request beating a decomposed horse being declined despite being presumably well-written? ...

Comment: You don't understand how meta voting works yet, do you. Please understand that down votes on meta only mean that someone disagrees with your premise. It has nothing to do with the quality of your question or request here -- only that your point is being voted on, and the voter does not support it. For instance, you'll notice that despite the down-votes, there's been no change to your reputation from them.

Comment: A large part of why this site works as well as it does is because we **don't** allow that sort of question here. Why would you want to break what works so well by allowing all of the noise and discussion that has spoiled all of the previous attempts? This site works because we keep that trash away. If you want the sort of site that you get when you allow that stuff, you can go to the other sites. There's a reason that this site *dwarfs all others*, and it's because we keep the clutter down and stick to the specific, technical issues.

Comment: also @Crusader disagreement is not closed mindedness

Comment: This wasn't meant to be a proposal. It was intended to start a discussion about ways to address the desire many obviously have for a more subjective discussion area. I'm not the first to express this. An absolute _refusal to even discuss_ alternative solutions (even a completely separate site!) looks an awful lot like closed-mindedness or herd mentality to me. The downvotes are probably people disagreeing that this should be on the main SO sites (I can agree), but that's not the point of the question here! Maybe I just worded this poorly, but this was *not meant to be a vote for subjectivity*.

Comment: @Sabre Tooth - I agree (it's obvious), but I think there is either a herd mentality problem here or an absolute unwillingness to discuss a possible solution to the problem posed. Either I worded this extremely poorly (quite possible) or the responses here are intentionally deflecting discussion on a solution to address the desire of many users to have a more subjective discussion area which is less interactive than a chat room or a lunch debate.  If it's the latter (deflection), isn't that a problem?

Comment: @Deduplicator You're right I made a mistake in tagging this with feature-request.  I can see that's clearly a nonstarter even being segregated with a wiki-like feature.  But the "complaint" was about the seeming lack of willingness to *discuss* how to address the problem.

Comment: @Crusader, this is because it has been discussed again, again, again and again - each time, the community decides that it wishes for the status quo.  Consider that many who downvote the idea and not leave a comment (as they do not have to) disagree and really don't have time (or patience) to go through the original arguments again.

Comment: @SabreTooth That's fine, but if all we're going to do is turn a blind eye to the fact that these discussions often take on 100+ (or more) upvotes and then get closed for being subjective, this is going to continue to hound meta again and again and again. I just hoped to hear a little more discussion about what to do about it.

Comment: @Crusader a lot of the highly upvoted ones are quite old - the rules of Stack Overflow have changed as it has got larger.   Read the duplicates, people are not willing to repeat themselves.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to make subjective topics "okay" here?

Not really.  There are a handful of notable exceptions, but they're still *exceptions* to the rule, rather than *being* the rule.

Let's not deny for one second that software engineering doesn't come with a lot of subjectivity.  I as a professional and hobbyist programmer do and create a lot of subjective practices or styles, or come up with subjective approaches to a problem.

That's *fine* for work and for hobbyists, but it doesn't fit within the model of a Q&A site.

Stack Exchange (overall) is seeking to be a place to get questions answered by experts.  In order to have a question answered by experts, it must be objective and clear.  Debating things that are subjective has had a tendency to turn experts away from that discussion.

If you *really* want the subjectivity, then you're looking in the wrong place for it.  That's simply not what Stack Exchange is about.

> The community here dwarfs all others, why not find a way to stop suppressing simple information gathering research?

Nobody is stopping anyone from doing this.  What's being stopped is having it presented as an objective result on the main sites.  You're welcome to get into subjective discussions or debates in Chat all you like, but the Q&A section of the site is very much not into that.

Again, I mention that there are [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1079354) [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7551/1079354) [that do](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2493331/1079354) [drift into](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273695/1079354) [the subjective territory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75980/1079354), but I maintain that this is the **exception** to the rule rather than the rule.  Do not look on these questions as a justification to *start* another subjective question.

> Aren't we squandering a potentially massive resource by blindly adhering to this single strict format?

There are exceptions made to this (notice a theme here?) when a question is indeed exemplary.  Mind you, this is done on a case-by-case basis, and it depends on the community's willingness to manicure and maintain these questions, so we're not really losing much.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: Strong disagreement with the premise here.  If the site was called "Not Programming Related", that's a direct invitation for off topic crap. Then why is it shocking to anyone that it ended up with lots of off topic garbage?  The kind of discussion I'm referring to is tangentially programming related but _strictly_ development/engineering and "best practice" related. We could argue that maybe an entirely new format should be used for such a site (I'd agree that's worthy of discussion), but I don't see any evidence that this concept really had a chance yet.

Comment: Comment above was a reply to gnat. @Makoto I explain the problem with "use chat" in the comment below the other question.  Basically it's far too time consuming and unproductive.  Not to mention a chat discussion is at the mercy of topic changes, distractions, and not nearly enough viewpoints.  So chat isn't the answer - the point of my post here was to discover whether there is a better possible alternative.

Comment: The other alternative is "forums".  Stack Exchange doesn't want to *become* a forum, so its only other outlet for something like this is chat.

Comment: The bottom line is this: There's clear demand and need for people to talk about non-objective topics, software recommendations, best practices, suggestions, or controversial views. There isn't a quality, active alternative out there (among "forums" or "question" sites). What's the solution to that problem?

Comment: The goal of this site is to assist people, not police others looking for advice or assistance. SE should build a separate forum (ex. Discourse) site which can be linked to, instead of the useless "chat" feature which doesn't even persist. If that solution isn't popular, what does the downvote mob here suggest people do for non-censored discussion of these topics?

Comment: @Manius:  Actually, the goal of the site is [laid out in the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - to be a library of detailed answers to every programming question.  Helping people happens as a natural side-effect to this goal.

Comment: @Manius:  Conversation and non-objective topics are well out of the scope of this site.  If you *really* crave those, nothing is stopping you from setting up your own, unofficial Discourse site to handle those.  It would be unfortunate though, given that we're really trying to pool that knowledge here.

Comment: That's why I just suggested an alternative site that's run by the same site owners (I think they develop Discourse too?). This could be integrated with SO and used to "convert" questions that are deemed subjective to forum posts.

Answer (score 0):

No. The community is specialized to handle objective questions. Most subjective questions either can be answered elsewhere, don't attract a sufficient body of interested users to form a site to answer them, or are unsuitable for the StackExchange format entirely.

For "simple information gathering research," where you want short explanations quickly, you can try chat.

Comment: Not addressing the intent of the post here. This wasn't a poll for putting subjective info on SO, it was supposed to be a discussion on how to address the subjective discussion problem. As for chat, who has hours to sit in a chat room? Posting a request for viewpoints takes little time to do and afterwards you can read as much of the response as you have time for.  Chat requires you (and your answerers) to be captive for long periods of time while your life is wasted waiting for people to type.

Comment: I'd also add - Chat doesn't persist. Most chat links get deleted, which helps nobody. If chats were limited to helping people with *very* specific problems that only pertained to them, it'd be fine. But currently it's used when someone decides there are "too many" comments, as an excuse to vandalize the comments area which may have helped others. (Personally I've better things to do with my time than police comments which are truncated/hidden by default anyway.)